# Loading sprites using JSON in Unity and C#

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I've used JSON in text and it works fine but when I added Sprites to it no sprite/image are being loaded it gives a null statement. here is my code for every script.  [CLICK HERE TO SEE THE PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kccGy.png)

First is my JSON script

```
{
  "Vehicles": [
    {
      "Make": "Toyota",
      "Model": "Camry",
      "Wheels": 4,
      "CarImage": "Assets/Resources/Sprites/Slide1.png"
    },
    {
      "Make": "Yamaha",
      "Model": "Di ko balo",
      "Wheels": 2,
      "CarImage": "Assets/Resources/Sprites/Slide1.png"
    },
    {
      "Make": "Ford",
      "Model": "Ranger",
      "Wheels": 4,
      "CarImage": "Assets/Resources/Sprites/Slide1.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Second are the serializable public classes to show in Game Object

```
public string Make;
public string Model;
public int Wheels;
public Sprite CarImage;
```

Third is to create a List of Object

```
public List<Vehicles> Vehicles = new List<Vehicles>();
```

Lastly the script that will be insert in Game Object

```
void Start () {
    TextAsset asset = Resources.Load("Vehicles") as TextAsset;

    if (asset != null) {
        VehicleList = JsonUtility.FromJson<VehiclesLists>(asset.text);
        foreach (Vehicles vehicle in VehicleList.Vehicles)
        {
            print(vehicle.Make);
            print(vehicle.Model);
            print(vehicle.Wheels);
            print(vehicle.CarImage);
        }

    } else
    {
        print("Asset is null");
    }
}
```

I only need for the sprite to show up in the debugging thanks

Comment: you want the spite itself to show or just the location?

Comment: I still don't have the GUI what I have right now is the Debug.Log() to show if ever it is valid or null.. I want the sprite itself to show and the location..

Comment: @styx sir, do you have ano solutions please

Comment: i dont fully understand what you want to

Comment: Do want to see the image so that you can understand it more precisely? the Image is on the top above the code please see. that is my problem no image is added on the sprite though i have my JSON file

Comment: so, in your example `vehicle.CarImage` gives you null?

Comment: YES ! Exactly sir what solution can I do?

Comment: @styx any solution can you give me sir?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 string json = "{\n  \"Vehicles\": [\n    {\n      \"Make\": \"Toyota\",\n      \"Model\": \"Camry\",\n      \"Wheels\": 4,\n      \"CarImage\": \"Assets/Resources/Sprites/Slide1.png\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Make\": \"Yamaha\",\n      \"Model\": \"Di ko balo\",\n      \"Wheels\": 2,\n      \"CarImage\": \"Assets/Resources/Sprites/Slide1.png\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Make\": \"Ford\",\n      \"Model\": \"Ranger\",\n      \"Wheels\": 4,\n      \"CarImage\": \"Assets/Resources/Sprites/Slide1.png\"\n    }\n  ]\n}";



          VehicleList = JsonUtility.FromJson<VehiclesLists>(json);

            foreach (var vehicle in VehicleList.Vehicles)
            {
                vehicle.CarImageSprite = Resources.Load(vehicle.CarImageStr, typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
                print(vehicle.CarImageStr);
            }


    public class Vehicle
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public int Wheels { get; set; }
        public string CarImageStr { get; set; }
        public Sprite CarImageSprite { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: **The name JsonCovert does not exist on the current.. **

Comment: @makemove sorry, fixed

Comment: fixed again, sorry i created the project with VS and not with unity , therefore those variable missmatch

Comment: You still need to change the json naming or the script naming for the string url. They won't match and won't work.